# How to get excel to recognize a number input as a date

Tags: excel, date

I want to change the default format of dates in excel sheets to follow a format that is 'yymmdd'. I dont want to include any slashes periods or dashes to separate the elements of the date. For example the 14th of May 2022, would simply be displayed as 220514.
The problem I'm running into is that excel sees me entering 220514 as a number and converts it to a date using its own method of adding the number I enter to the default start date of 01/01/1900.  If I manually change the date in the formula bar to what I want it to be, it will display correctly, but this wont be feasible if I have to enter a large amount of data. If I enter the date in a format with slashes (22/05/14) it also works, but I want to avoid having to do that if possible. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You'd need to enter valid dates. One workaround could be: Change the column formatting to text instead. Then enter all dates in the format of 'yymmdd'. Excel should keep all values as is for now. Next step is to use text-to-columns on a fixed width, click date and choose the 'YMD' format. After you done the in-place replacement you can change the number format of this column back to 'yymmdd'.

Comment: You could write VBA event code to interpret and convert your input on the fly